# Deleting elasticsearch indices which are older than an hour via curator

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I am having some indices in elasticsearch whose naming format is `elk-console-YYYY-MM-DDtHH`. For example:-

```
elk-console-2016-03-30t14
elk-console-2016-03-30t16
```

I want to delete all indices which are more than 1 hour old using [curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html). So I tried executing the below command:-

```
curator --host localhost delete indices --older-than 1 --time-unit hours --timestring '%Y-%m-%dt%H'
```

But it is giving me the following ouput:-

```
2016-04-22 16:27:36,049 INFO      Job starting: delete indices
2016-04-22 16:27:36,058 INFO      Pruning Kibana-related indices to prevent accidental deletion.
2016-04-22 16:27:36,058 WARNING   No indices matched provided args: {'regex': None, 'index': (), 'suffix': None, 'newer_than': None, 'closed_only': False, 'prefix': None, 'time_unit': 'hours', 'timestring': u'%Y-%m-%dt%H', 'exclude': (), 'older_than': 1, 'all_indices': False}
No indices matched provided args: {'regex': None, 'index': (), 'suffix': None, 'newer_than': None, 'closed_only': False, 'prefix': None, 'time_unit': 'hours', 'timestring': u'%Y-%m-%dt%H', 'exclude': (), 'older_than': 1, 'all_indices': False}
```

I also tried executing the below command:-

```
curator --host localhost delete indices --older-than 1 --time-unit hours --timestring '%Y-%m-%dt%H' --prefix elk-console-
```

But still getting the below error:-

```
2016-04-22 16:48:43,848 INFO      Job starting: delete indices
2016-04-22 16:48:43,856 INFO      Pruning Kibana-related indices to prevent accidental deletion.
2016-04-22 16:48:43,856 WARNING   No indices matched provided args: {'regex': None, 'index': (), 'suffix': None, 'newer_than': None, 'closed_only': False, 'prefix': u'elk-console-', 'time_unit': 'hours', 'timestring': u'%Y-%m-%dt%H', 'exclude': (), 'older_than': 1, 'all_indices': False}
No indices matched provided args: {'regex': None, 'index': (), 'suffix': None, 'newer_than': None, 'closed_only': False, 'prefix': u'elk-console-', 'time_unit': 'hours', 'timestring': u'%Y-%m-%dt%H', 'exclude': (), 'older_than': 1, 'all_indices': False}
```

Can some one please help me what `timestring` format should I use in my case?

Environment:-

- Curator 3.5.1
- Elasticsearch - 2.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by untergeek [here](https://github.com/elastic/curator/issues/602)

> The problem is that it's treating the `t` as a special character, like a
>   `.` or a `-`. This is the first time I've encountered anyone using this
>   syntax, as most people have used hyphens or dots to separate things.
>
> I may back port the fix to 3.x, but chances are good that I will not.
>   I'm adding the fix to the 4.x branch now.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you're simply missing the [`--prefix` option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/prefix.html)

```
curator --host localhost delete indices --older-than 1 --time-unit hours --timestring %Y-%m-%dt%H --prefix elk-console
```

Comment: It seems you have added the `-` at the end of the prefix, you shouldn't.

Comment: same error. 
`2016-04-22 17:09:13,202 WARNING   No indices matched provided args: {'regex': None, 'index': (), 'suffix': None, 'newer_than': None, 'closed_only': False, 'prefix': u'elk-console', 'time_unit': 'hours', 'timestring': u'%Y-%m-%dt%H', 'exclude': (), 'older_than': 1, 'all_indices': False}
No indices matched provided args: {'regex': None, 'index': (), 'suffix': None, 'newer_than': None, 'closed_only': False, 'prefix': u'elk-console', 'time_unit': 'hours', 'timestring': u'%Y-%m-%dt%H', 'exclude': (), 'older_than': 1, 'all_indices': False}`

Comment: I think the `timestring` is not matching because of `t`.

Comment: Oh, just remove the single quotes around the timestring!

Comment: No luck still :( . Entered timestring as `%Y-%m-%dt%H` .

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely that the index name pattern reflects local time, but Curator does its calculations in UTC.  The solution is a software change to allow timezone offsets.

Comment: I don't think that is quite the case. I have updated this in the github issues - https://github.com/elastic/curator/issues/602